# Read content of IMAGE attributes outside of GeneXus

Tags: php, genexus

In GeneXus I store an image in an Image type attribute, in SQL Server that field is VARBINARY(MAX) and the content is:

"0x89504E470D0A1A0A000000..."

I understand that it is the HEXA of the binary. What I want to do is to be able to raise that image outside of GeneXus, in this case PHP
How does GeneXus store that image? Because I tried to convert that HEXA to String and then to BASE64 but I couldn't find the content and display the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

```
<?php
// Value of Image Data Type
$imagen = '0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484...';
?>

<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(pack('H*',substr($imagen, 2)));?>" />
```

Cheers